# Prove commutativity of a particular element of a group

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group in which the element $x$ is the only one of order 2. Show that $x$ commutes with every other element of $G$

How could I prove the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. Let $y \in G$ be any element. We have for $g := yxy^{-1}$, that 
$$ g^2 = yx^2y^{-1} = 1 $$
So $g$ is of order $2$. Now what elements of order 2 $G$ has.